# Simple avg query on large table much slower in PostgreSQL than SQL Server

Tags: postgresql, group-by, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a database with three tables `items`, `parameters` and `measurements` in both servers and want to query the `measuerment` table. But the query is much slower in PostgeSQL (9.4) vs SQL Server (2012).

`measurements`:

```
column         | type                 | attributes
---------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
id             | int/serial           | (identity) primary key
measuretime    | datetime/timestamp   | not null
parameter_id   | int                  | not null (foreign key) references parameters(id)
item_id        | int                  | not null (foreign key) references items(id)
value          | float                | not null
```

and two `nonclustered index` on `measuretime` and `parameter_id`

I've inserted 2.609.280 rows in `items` (half a year with 5 seconds between each) and 31.311.360 rows in `measurements` (for each item with 12 parameters).

When I now try to query the average value per day per parameter it performs really well on SQL Server (00:00:02) but pretty bad on PostgreSQL (00:00:53).

SQL Server Query:

```
select parameter_id, convert(date, measuretime), avg(value)
from measurements
group by parameter_id, convert(date, measuretime)
```

PostgreSQL Query:

```
select parameter_id, date(measuretime), avg("value")
from measurements
group by parameter_id, date(measuretime)
```

Is there anything I can do about this? create an index? some server settings? change the query?

Comment: It's not clear why the difference might be so extreme, but if you have multiple cores on the machine and this is the only query you are running, I would expect SQL Server to be much faster.  Postgres will not use more than 1 core for a single query, whereas SQL Server could be using 8 or more cores for the query depending on your hardware and MAXDOP settings.  At a glance, this looks like a query that SQL Server would be able to parallelize quite efficiently.  So this might be at least one of the factors explaining the difference you are seeing.

Comment: is there any way to get postgres to speed it up / also use multiple cores?

Comment: Without an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output one can only guess what's wrong.  My best idea is that you need an index on `date(measuretime)`, as an index on the column itself cannot support the query you have.

Comment: Actually, I guess the index should be more effective if it comprises both grouping parameters: `(parameter_id, date(measuretime))`. Or it may be good for nothing and PostgreSQL decides it is better to sequential scan and then sort (or hash, or...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 9.6 [Date constructors were fixed.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6.html)

> Improve speed of the output functions for timestamp, time, and date data types (David Rowley, Andres Freund)

You can see the [commit fest for this here.](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/7/343/) It's roughly 20x faster. In addition 9.6 supports parallel sequential scans. So this may be 20x faster on a single core. And, the whole scan may be able to use all of the cores on your system.

1. Download 9.6
2. Try again.
3. Get back with the results.

Comment: On my Windows laptop Postgres 9.6.2 could do a sample query with 38 million rows in 4 seconds with 4 workers: https://explain.depesz.com/s/l5P and 3 seconds with 6 workers: https://explain.depesz.com/s/7Et8

Comment: I'm currently not anymore involved with that project (nor postgres databases for that matter as we stuck to SQL Server after our performance tests), so I probably won't come back with results anytime soon. But we always suspected that the date conversation and non-multicore support where to blame so I think your answer seems pretty sound.